# Strange behavior in implementing LEFT_RIGHT sliding menu

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu

**Dears,**

I'm new to Android, and try to use SlidingMenu in my project. 
I want to create an application with two sliding menus same as Facebook.

With these steps I had crated my application:

1. Download and add SlidingMenu library into my work-space.
2. Download and add actionbarsherlock library to my work-space.
3. In SlidingMenu library I add actionbarsherlock as a reference library.
4. In SlidingMenu library, I extend `SlidingActivity.java` with actionbarsherlock: 
   `public class SlidingActivity extends SherlockActivity  implements SlidingActivityBase`
5. In my application, I add reference to SlidingMenu library.
6. In my application, I extend my main activity to use `SlidingActivity` :
   `public class MainMenu extends SlidingActivity`

**My main activity code:**

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity;

public class MainMenu extends SlidingActivity {
    SlidingMenu  menu;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (enableHomeIconActionBack() || enableHomeIconActionSlidingMenu()) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null){
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.sliding_menu_shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.sliding_menu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu_frame);

        menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.vehicles_tree);
        menu.setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (enableHomeIconActionSlidingMenu()
                    && menu != null) {
                menu.toggle();
            } else if (enableHomeIconActionBack()) {
                onCustomBackPressed();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            onCustomBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }

    // If sliding menu is showing, we need to hide it on the first back button
    // press.
    private void onCustomBackPressed() {
        if (menu != null
                && menu.isMenuShowing()) {
            menu.toggle();
        } else {
            this.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets activity home icon to have up icon and on press act as device back
     * button press.
     * 
     * @return Activation state.
     */
    public boolean enableHomeIconActionBack() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Sets activity home icon to be as a sliding menu invoke icon and on press
     * call toggle command for the sliding menu.
     * 
     * @return Activation state.
     */
    public boolean enableHomeIconActionSlidingMenu() {
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Now, `menu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu_frame);` will show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF00FF" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

And `menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.vehicles_tree);` will show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#FF0F00FF">
</RelativeLayout>
```

**The following snapshots describe the strange behavior:**

[Click to show image](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/4166/47ry.jpg)

1. Main activity.
2. When you swipe **right** on the **screen**.
3. When you swipe **left** on the **screen**.
4. When you swipe **right** from **left screen edge**. This activity covers the entire screen and it is showing the activity attached to `setBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);`, I noticed that by changing the attached layout.

I don't want the forth screen, what I'm doing wrong?

Regards,,
Ali Alaswad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
public class MainMenu extends SlidingActivity {
```

to this line

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
```

SlidingActivity extends behaviour number 4 with "setBehindContentView" to the normal android "Activity" so changing it back to android "Activity" will remove that unwanted behaviour

Comment: @captain overflow its not working for me, when i changed the SlidingActivity to Activity, the activity is not recognising the "setBehindContentView" method

Comment: @Lalit Google released DrawerLayout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

I prefer to use the official tools when they come up so I would change to that.

If you still want to use the SlidingMenu Library: "setBehindContentView" is part of SlidingActivity so it will not work in Activity. Instead, You get a menu from "setMenu" and the other from "setSecondaryMenu"

Answer (score 0):

```
setBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
```

This sets the layout of the primary menu (what happens when you slide left), so you should change this to use `R.layout.sliding_menu_frame` and remove `setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu_frame)`

I'm not sure why calling `setMenu` doesn't overwrite that, but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Android library that allows you to easily create applications with slide-in menus. You may use it in your Android apps provided that you cite this project and include the license in your app. Thanks!

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu